# WCF: How to get requested Web method name in HttpModule and ServiceAuthorizationManager

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-security, httpmodule

I want to setting up user authentication and auhorization using 2 methods:

1) `HttpModule`

2) `ServiceAuthorizationManager` and override `CheckAccessCore`

I have a role based authorization and I want to get name of requested web method to do authorization based on web methods.

How I can get requested web method?

Thanks

Comment: you using webHttpBinding ?

Comment: No I'm using `BasicHttpBinding`

Comment: in that case also below answer i provided should work. please check.

Comment: did u get this working?

Comment: It works in `CheckAccessCore` but not in `HttpModule`

Comment: which event you hooking to in `HttpModule` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement sometime back and remember vaguely using something like below to serve the purpose :

```
protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            string actionName = GetActionName(operationContext);
            /* do what all further authorization check you want to do
             * like "can user access method with actionname="Create"*/
        }

        private static string GetActionName(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            string action;

            if (operationContext.RequestContext != null)
            {
                action = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.Action;
            }
            else
            {
                action = operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action;
            }

            if (action == null)// REST Service - webHttpBinding
            {
                action = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch == null || WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.Data == null
                         ? String.Empty : WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.Data.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                action = action.Split('/').Last();
            }
            return action;
        }
```

You can tweak above code snippet to better closely meet your requirement but for sure this will give you clear picture on how to extract `method` name.

Comment: It works in `CheckAccessCore` but not in `HttpModule`

Comment: `Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: not sure - but reading SOAP message and fetching method name causing any issue there ?

Comment: No at first glance. But How to get method name from SOAP message?

Comment: looks post here : https://forums.asp.net/t/1286024.aspx?Reading+method+name+and+its+parameters+from+soap+body discuss that only.